# How to load dxf2Shp Converter plugin from the in build python console in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I'm trying to write a script to automate loading of dxf2Shp Converter using the build-in python console. The script should open the pop up of that plug-in. I've tried using `.available_plugins/.loadPlugin()` but it's not working for me.

Any suggestions?